# Loop through array and add parameters to sql query in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, loops

I want to assign an sql sting to a variable in Javascript. But I want to loop through an array to build par of the sql statement.

static sql:

```
var tag = [fun, beach, sun];

var sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable "
            +"WHERE id > 5" //...
            // loop through tag array and add to the sql
            function tagQuery(tag) {
                for (var i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {
                var tagQuery = "AND WHERE tags like %'"+tag[i]+"'%";
                return tagQuery;
                }; 
            }
```

It is not clear to me how to get each result of the tagQuery function to be added to the sql sting?

**EDIT**: maybe a more clear way to ask the question is: How can I get each iteration of the tagQuery function to be joined with the sql variable?

Comment: I see you've already marked as answer... DID IT WORK?  Your original question, using `LIKE`, will find values of `tags` where all your values occur *IN THE SAME STRING*:  `tags LIKE '%fun%%beach%%sun%'`.  Is that really what you want?  Or are you actually trying to find situations with `tags LIKE '%fun%'` and `tags LIKE '%beach%'` and `tags LIKE '%sun%'`?

Comment: No, Rusty's answer did not work (at first I thought it did). I made a mistake, I am really after: tags LIKE '%fun%' OR tags LIKE '%beach%' OR ...

Comment: Then how about  `str += " OR tags like '%" + tag[i] + "%' "`, within the function, then replace `var i = 0` with `var i = 1` (the beginning of the loop), then make the last two lines `sql += " AND tags like '%" + tag[0] + "%' "; sql += tagQuery(tag);`

Comment: Well, the last two lines also need to place parentheses around all the conditions for `tags`, for example: `sql += " AND (tags like '%" + tag[0] + "%' "; sql += tagQuery(tag) + ")";`

Comment: I posted my suggestions as another answer, but I upvoted Rusty's answer, because he did the "heavy lifting" ;)

Comment: I don't know how likely it is, that other searchers will land on this page... but since people finding a page will often try the marked answer as a "proven solution"... consider **posting** what you actually did, that finally worked... (probably with an "OR", instead of an "AND").  For example, you could add it as a comment under the checked answer, or perhaps as an addition to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tag = [fun, beach, sun];

var sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id > 5";

function tagQuery(tag) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {
        str += " AND tags like '%" + tag[i] + "%' "
    }
    return str;
}

sql += tagQuery(tag);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7P4us/2/

Comment: Don't you want `IN` (with parentheses and commas) instead of `LIKE`?

Comment: @Doug_Ivison - I believe you cannot use the wildcards with `IN` that is why we need the `LIKE`

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Good point... but wouldn't the above treat 'fun', 'beach', and 'sun' as portions of **one** string, being built (`LIKE '%fun%%beach%%sun'`), instead of a list of values for `tags`?  I'll re-post my previous comment as a clarifying question to the OP.

Comment: @Doug_Ivison - The example above will produce three lines it will wind up looking like this `AND tags like '%fun%' AND tags like '%beach%' AND tags like '%sun%'`  The loop will append a whole new line each iteration.   It should probably have some `OR`s in there too.   Example `AND (tags like '%fun%' OR tags like '%beach%' OR tags like '%sun%')`

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Thanks, that's clear.  The `OR`s would address what I was talking about.

Comment: This answer does not seem to work because when I do: sql += tagQuery(tag); it will only return the last iteration of the tagQuery loop, instead of all of the iterations like:  
" AND tags like '%"fun"%' AND tags like '%"beach"%' AND tags like '%"sun"%' "

Comment: I think you can probably piece together what you are missing based on the information given..

Comment: The original question is still not clear, how can I get all of the iterations of the loop to be joined to the sql variable, not just the last iteration?

Comment: His question was unclear, and an error in his proposed code furthered the confusion:  he wants lines containing **any** of those strings, **not** lines containing all of those strings.

Comment: I see your point, though, that `sql += tagQuery(tag);` is returning all iterations, not just the last iteration.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help and patience with this, and apologies for not being more clear. Yes, there was an issue with my implementation. I now have it working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** 
 
I took out the `tagQuery` function altogether, after you commented: 
`sql += tagQuery(tag);  ...will only return the last iteration of the tagQuery loop`

```
var tag = ['fun', 'beach', 'sun'];
var sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id > 5";

if (tag[0] != null) {
    sql += " AND (tags like '%" + tag[0] + "%' "; 
}

if (tag[1] != null) {
    for (var i = 1; i < tag.length; i++) {
        sql += " OR tags like '%" + tag[i] + "%' ";
    }
}

if (tag[0] != null) {
    sql += ")";
}
```

But note:  the jsFiddle link that Rusty put in a comment, since, shows that the tagQuery function **can** return **all** iterations... so seeing only the last iteration was probably in your implementation.